# How to move page up when AdSense is not showing up

Tags: adsense

Is it any way to move the page up when AdSense is not showing any ads?

We have a page with 750px - 200px AdSense space ad but sometimes ads are not showing so there is a blank space on the page.
Is it possible to move the whole page content up when AdSense is not showing any ads?

Thanks a lot!